# Shopify Create a customer with email address in shopify store

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app

I have built a store and I created a form to input email. 
Once submit button is clicked, I want to create a customer using API.

How can I do this?

Should I have to create a Private App in PHP file to use API?

Is there anyway I can use to AjaxAPI to do this?

If I have to build Private APP then should I send request to other domain and back to store in that PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GraphQL Strofront API to create a customer.

Refer to https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api/reference/mutation/customercreate

But you need to include a password as well for the call.

---

If you don't want to include a password you will need to find an App or create a custom App yourself.

If you submit the form to a separate domain you can use a Private App as long as you handle the logic on the server side and not on the front-end side.But please don't use it on the front-end ( I mean revealing the `Api Key` and `Api Secret` publicly ) since that will be a huge security risk.